# EJB pooling in JBoss EAP 6 - Are there any downsides to just setting a really large value for max-pool-size?

Tags: jboss-eap-6

We have a large knowledge management application that we are migrating from JBoss EAP 4.3 to EAP 6.4. We had some issues with a parallel MDB-driven process failing (with the error message referenced in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978934/jboss-as-7-1-1-ejb-3-ejb-pool-error)) which was traced back to exhaustion of the SLSB pool. The MDB threads were requesting a particular stateless session bean three levels deep (to open new transactions), so 10 concurrent processes were enough to exhaust the pool and cause a deadlock with the default `max-pool-size` of 20.

The solution was to assign that particular SLSB to its own pool and ensure `max-pool-size` was set large enough so there would always be enough bean instances available (75 in our case, as the culprit MDB process is limited to 25 instances itself). We will doubtless find a lot of other cases in our application that may require or at least benefit from setting up similar custom pool sizes.

The point is, the default value for the MDB and SLSB maximum pool sizes in JBoss EAP - 20 instances of each bean - seems absurdly low. I would like to do some profiling to see how many EJB instances we have in play during typical usage of the application, so I could know what pool sizes we need to allow.

- What is the rationale for the default `max-pool-size` value of 20?
- Will there be any harm in just setting the `max-pool-size` of the
  default    `slsb-strict-max-pool` and `mdb-strict-max-pool` to some
  arbitrarily    large value? I recognise this could increase the peak
  memory allocation   used by the application if it goes instantiating
  a lot of EJB instances, but since EJBs are only instantiated and added to the pool on demand, how different is it to the alternative of not using pooling? (For context, I did a quick audit and counted 34 MDBs and 775 SLSBs in our application.)
- Is it best to match the `max-pool-size` of my EJB pools closely to expected number of EJB instances that the application will require, or can I just set a large `max-pool-size` value on everything and leave at that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to the `max-poo-size` of 20, it is really hard to come up with a default value.  If this were set to 100, then a user on a single core system could easily overwhelm the CPU.  It comes down to how many cores are available, what the MDB workload looks like, and how much else is going on in the application.

If you have 32 cores available to you, there is nothing else going on in the application, and the work done during MDB processing is very small, then a pool of 20 is potentially too small.

MDBs will always be pooled, as will stateless session beans.

You can set the pool max to be a high value, and this won't hurt anything.  Keeping in mind that for MDBs, a JMS session is needed for activation.  The default number of sessions is 15.  So for MDBs, you need to match up the number of sessions and the instance pool size in order to get the desired number of activated MDBs.  The number of sessions is configured in the MDB activation deployment spec.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. With regard to the MDBs, I did also find out about the default limit of 15 sessions and so made a special pool for our one MDB that we'd previously configured for 25 instances. Wondering how many unique pools I might need to cover for the usage requirements of all our 800+ beans (and whether I should focus on making a few consolidated pools of different sizes, or just embiggen the default pool) is what sparked the question.

Comment: Our first concern is that the application should work as it did under the old platform; our second is that we hopefully aren't any worse off having gone to EAP 6. I understood the pooling to be a performance tactic - trading the memory consumed by EJB instances for the computation saved from not reinstantiating them all over the place. However, your answer seems to imply that one concern for choosing a small default value was to limit the number of EJB instances doing work (and unintended throttling is what I'm now concerned about for our application). So, is it about going faster or slower?

Comment: The number of MDB instances and pool size is highly application and deployment specific.  If the MDBs are light, and you have the hardware for 800 threads, then by all means go for it.  My personal experience has been that I more often see people trying to spin up a very large number of threads and swamping their processors.  Just be mindful.  Actually know and test at what point increasing the number of threads is counter productive.

Comment: Okay. This still seems like cross-purposes; after all, in EAP 4.3 we had no pooling, EJBs were instantiated on demand and we implemented our own throttling on the number of threads where we found that of benefit. All the doco on EJB pooling only talks about the performance intent. Yet when we drop our application into the new framework, with the default settings we find errors from pool exhaustion, and throttling over our whole application. So it caused some grief, when we just wanted it to work like before. But it being what it is, I can accept it now as another tool to tune our application.